# ActiveMQ Artemis: full disk policy

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17. I've set up the address full message policy to PAGING and ran some crash tests. When the disk is full, I'm getting the message "AMQ222212: Disk Full! Blocking message production on address...". Is there a setup to raise an error to the producers instead of blocking them?

Regards
Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the disk is full the only option is to block. However, if the protocol doesn't support flow control an exception will be thrown. This is noted in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html#max-disk-usage).

For what it's worth, individual addresses can be configured to behave differently when they reach `max-size-bytes`. One of those options is to return a failure to producers, e.g.:

```xml
<address-full-policy>FAIL</address-full-policy>
```

See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html#configuration) for more details.